# How can I calculate element dimensions based on sibling element dimensions?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to find a way to calculate an element's height based on the height of its sibling elements. In the code snippet below, children one and three have a height of 20%, and a max-height of 70px. I need to find a way to get child two to fill the remainder of the height, regardless of the container size, which is variable `height: calc(100vh - 12vmin - 40px);`. I have tried media queries and the calc() function, but neither work because of the variable container height. I am thinking that I will need to use JS, but any solution without it is preferable.

Thanks for any help!

P.S. If you have a solution with JS, please use vanilla JS.

```css
#container {
  border: 4px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100vh - 12vmin - 40px);
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#childOne {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20%;
  max-height: 70px;
}

#childTwo {
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60%;
}

#childThree {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20%;
  max-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="childOne"></div>
  <div id="childTwo"></div>
  <div id="childThree"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS flexbox is the way to go.

Change height on container to `height: 100vh`, add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`.

For childTwo remove the setting of height altogether and add `flex:1`.

```css
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    #container {
      border: 4px solid #000000;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #childOne {
      border: 2px solid blue;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 20%;
      max-height: 70px;
    }

    #childTwo {
      border: 2px solid red;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      flex: 1;
    }

    #childThree {
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 20%;
      max-height: 70px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="childOne"></div>
      <div id="childTwo"></div>
      <div id="childThree"></div>
    <div>
```

Comment: You can put back in the variable height and this should still work. So long as you set height on the container with some amount (not percentage unless it's parent has a set height), then the middle div will fill the remaining space.